# Selling fraudulent goods in the Rova

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, heresy, real-estate

I was walking in the Rova (Jewish Quarter of the Old City) today after Shacharit and I noticed something which I found to be quite disconcerting. There is a Messianic "Jewish" store selling "tashmishei kedusha" on Rechov HaYehudim. Due to the great number of Jews who visit the Rova looking for souvenirs and tashmishei kedusha, this presents a clear case of fraud.

I'm not going to get involved in this on the ground, but I wonder what the halacha would be for those who do have the wherewithal to act.

In particular,
Would it be mutar for the landlord to evict the tenant or to cause undue financial stress to cause the above?

Comment: should just move them to the christian quarter where they belong ..

Comment: @CashCow, completely agree. I went in there to see how outrageous their prices were and noticed the Messianic symbols (not to be confused with all of the Meshichist narischkeit throughout J'lem, but that's another issue which has been discussed already). I immediately left and made a mental note to ask this question.

Comment: Fraud is when there's intent to deceive. (IANAL.) I don't see any intent to deceive here: after all, don't the proprietors maintain that these items are in fact _tashmishe k'dusha_? (Doubtless they're breaking other _halachos_, but I don't see the fraud issue.)

Comment: Were they clearly marketed as messianic Jewish [sic]? as opposed to Jewish?

Comment: @mevaqesh, they looked like a judaica store. You have to look closely to see the heretical nature of the store.